# Does this answer really deserve so many upvotes?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584510/6217177) has close to a hundred upvotes (at the time of this question, at least). It is a simple, obvious answer, which many other people have also given, but because it was the first answer to the problem and so many people viewed the question it has a disproportionate amount of upvotes. Does this answer deserve all those upvotes?

EDIT: This question is different from the duplicate; it is not about upvotes going to the authors; it is about them going to the answerers.

Comment: Why shouldn't it deserve it?

Comment: @Rizier123 Other people have put the same answer and got only four upvotes. The answer I have linked to isn't particularly special.

Comment: People saw it, presumably it helped them so they upvoted it. Is there something you're suggesting we need to do about that?

Comment: It was special because it was the *first* answer.

Comment: "asked 4 years ago viewed 102611 times"

Comment: @RobertLongson It's just because it doesn't make sense; they were literally lucky to get so many upvotes. There were other people who answered the same thing. Any one of them could have got a hundred upvotes. So he doesn't really deserve it, no one does.

Comment: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172)

Comment: Also, check out the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7584510/timeline): it got 4 upvotes when it was written, and then no more than one or two a month for 4 years.

Comment: Programmers tend to have rather trivial problems.  Still, only 0.089% of all the ones that saw that answer thought it was useful, nothing much to brag about..

Comment: @theB Even though the upvotes were over time, why did people even bother upvoting it? The answer was the same as the other ones, basically.

Comment: @theB This is pretty interesting and related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313474/should-really-old-questions-and-answers-allow-to-be-upvoted?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean *"deserve"*? Why shouldn't it get upvotes if people find it useful? Why should people who gave the same answer but later be rewarded for that? *"they were literally lucky"* - yes, but: so what?

Comment: I would expect this particular case is because of python 3 adoption. Devs familiar with python 2 are going to hit that, google it and find that answer. The suggestion that people who answer that question years later "deserve" upvotes is pretty unlikeable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Suppose today you were randomly selected by SO to get 1,000 upvotes on every answer you ever wrote. Wouldn't that be unfair to all the other users, because you now have more rep than Jon Skeet without doing anything? This is an exaggerated example; but it's what's happening here.

Comment: That's not what's happening at all. The votes came in very slowly over the course of 4 years, and as Hans pointed out, only a very small percentage of the views translated into votes. People upvoted it because it helped them, or because they liked the font, or because Tim found his keys. Also they probably didn't vote for the other answer to the same degree because it was _added two years later_.

Comment: @u8y7541 stupid example is stupid. It's not like the user didn't do anything, *they wrote a useful answer*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would give the money to a charity or all the people I know so I can help more people.

Comment: @u8y7541 and if you get a lot of rep you're welcome to spend it on bounties. It's still irrelevant; stop complaining about perceived injustice and write some useful posts of your own.

Comment: ...[Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271985/laziness-is-rewarded-big-time-by-the-reputation-system)

Comment: If anything, I'd argue that the [dupe answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15848310/1842065) posted ~2 years later and currently sitting at +7 (now +6) does not deserve so many upvotes.

Comment: Between all that needs attention on this site, trivial but decent answers with an undue amount of upvotes are very much at the bottom of the pile.

Comment: @Magisch What about questions about actual problems with have too many downvotes? xD

Comment: @u8y7541: "*It's just because it doesn't make sense; they were literally lucky to get so many upvotes.*" Guess what? ***Life isn't fair!*** Deal with it and move on.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know, but we should make it as fair as we can...

Comment: @u8y7541: How? By denying people the right to vote how they want to vote? By arbitrarily imposing your idea of "good answer" onto everyone else? Whether an answer "deserves" its score is an opinion. And yours is no better than anyone else's.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wasn't thinking of trying to impose my idea of a "good answer" on anyone else, this post is for discussion; that's why there's a discussion tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see what you mean - I have deleted trivial answers of my own myself, because I was embarrassed about the huge number of upvotes they received.

This should remain a voluntary act, though.

Putting people (moderators, high rep users...) in charge about which answers "deserve" what number of upvotes  becomes really problematic really quickly. Who gets to decide what is "deserving" to what degree? Who should get to override the community in judging an answer's quality, and why? Why is helping tens of thousands of people not "deserving" of their upvotes?

The way it currently works, everyone has a vote, and everyone knows the system isn't perfect and sometimes you get loads of rep for trivial stuff.

The only consequence is that to judge someone's *actual* skill in a certain field, you need to look past the rep, at people's actual track records.